# Javascript submit function working and not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I hesitate to ask this as it is a bit complex, but I will try to make it simple.

I have a page with several form fields.

I submit the page via a submit script (note more is done in this submit script, but I am leaving it out for simplicity

```
 function do_file_form_submit(gonext) {
 var f = document.getElementById('file_form');
 f.gonext.value = gonext;
 alert(gonext);
 f.submit();
 }
```

Please note that there are other variables included in this function.  gonext is not the only one, but I am leaving the others out in this case to keep it simple.

My HTML for simplicity sake looks like this:

```
 <form name="file_form" id=file_form action="<?= $this->URL('#', 'UpdateUploadUser', array('mode'=>'upload', 'ID'=>$_GET['ID']));?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="oneitem">

 <button name="submit1"  id="submit1" onclick="do_file_form_submit(2);"><img src="<?=$theme;?>/images/12addphoto32px.png">Save Settings Then Upload/Register Another</button>
```

On the backend side within the "UpdateUploadUser" function we have a checker which checks each submitted field to see if it is empty or not.  If it is empty, it returns:

```
        $this->chk = new mVal($event);

                    if(!$this->chk->Validate()) {
            $this->mode = 'error_redisplay';
                            //$this->mode='Error';
                            return;
                    }
```

If all info is there, then the script continues and runs as expected.  So, here is the issue.

If all information is there, and I click the button, then all works fine.  The file_form submit JS ALERTS the gonext value and the script runs and updates as it should.

HOWEVER, if an item is missing, then the validation script runs and "RETURNS".

Once the page has been returned, if you THEN attempt to click the submit button, the page STILL submits as it should, but the file_form submit script seems as if it doesn't even run, so that the gonext value is not passed at all.

So, I am trying to figure out how the submission of the form is still happening apart from this do_file_form_submit script.  Is there something having to do with "return" that I don't know about?

Hope that makes sense and thanks for any help!

Craig

Comment: When the form data is valid, what does your php script do finally? redirection? text output?

Comment: Hi Edgar.  Thanks for responding.  Yes, when it is valid, it runs through the entire function updating all of the DB fields with the various form information (again, I all of that code out for simplicity).  At the end of that, it determines what to do next based on the gonext value.  i.e.  if($event->properties('gonext') == '1') { do this }

Comment: Ok, but finally does it return HTML on success?

Comment: Yes.  If it goes through successfully after a good validation, it does what it is supposed to do based on the gonext value, i.e. if gonext=1, then go to the next item to be edited, if gonext=2 copy the current data to the next item to be edited, etc.  

IF, after the the page has been returned due to validation issues, I correct the issue and then re-submit, it runs through the entire function as it normally would.  HOWEVER, the problem is, the gonext value is 0 or empty, so at the end of the function, it does not do what it should.

Comment: As a follow up to this, this appears to be only happening in Chrome.  I tested it in Firefox and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Review your code

```
 function do_file_form_submit(gonext) {
     var f = document.getElementById('file_form');
     f.gonext.value = gonext;//f.gonext. i can not find gonext in ur form. just oneitem  try something like f.oneitem.value = gonext; i believe that is where the //problem occurs
     alert(gonext);
     f.submit();
     }
```

in nutshell, replace the line:

```
f.gonext.value = gonext;
```

with

```
document.file_form.value = gonext;
```

and then submit like

```
document.file_form.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.  While I left some out for simplicity, in that JS function there, there actually are other items, i.e. f.cat4.value or f.cat2.value = f.cat3_1.options[f.cat3_1.selectedIndex].value;

So, it looks like your code might would not work in that case?  Again, I left that out for simplicity, but maybe I should have included it.